# How to hide YouTube video recommendations

Tags: youtube

Is there a plugin or a proxy site, which shows YouTube in a "focused" mode, that is, it shows only the video, that one has opened without additional video suggestions on the sidebar/below?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure [invidio.us](https://invidio.us) to work just like you described. Just click on the **Preferences** button in the top-right corner of the site, then untick the box *'Show related videos?'*.